# Android live wallpaper can't open settings page

Tags: java, android, settings, live-wallpaper

I am trying to make a live wallpaper and I have faced an error that I can't solve. Here is the code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.cclever.fourmyword">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">

        <service android:name=".LiveWallpaper"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/livewallpaper" />

        </service>


        <activity android:label="@string/livewallpaper_settings"
            android:name=".LiveWallpaperSettings"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

LiveWallpaper.java

```
package ir.cclever.fourmyword;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class LiveWallpaper extends WallpaperService
{

    public static final String  SHARED_PREFS_NAME   = "livewallpapersettings";

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine()
    {
        return new TestPatternEngine();
    }

    class TestPatternEngine extends Engine implements
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        private SharedPreferences   mPreferences;

        Random rand;

        String firstSentence = null;
        Integer firstSize = 50;
        String secondSentence = null;
        Integer secondSize = 50;
        String thirdSentence = null;
        Integer thirdSize = 50;
        String forthSentence = null;
        Integer forthSize = 50;

        Point firstOriginal;
        Point firstCurrent;
        Point firstDes;
        Point secondOriginal;
        Point secondCurrent;
        Point secondDes;
        Point thirdOriginal;
        Point thirdCurrent;
        Point thirdDes;
        Point forthOriginal;
        Point forthCurrent;
        Point forthDes;

        Line firstLine;
        Line secondLine;
        Line thirdLine;

        String firstColor;
        String secondColor;
        String thirdColor;
        String forthColor;

        Bitmap back = null;
        Bitmap cover = null;
        String whichTheme;
        Boolean coverEnabled = true;

        TestPatternEngine(){
            mPreferences = LiveWallpaper.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            mPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
            onSharedPreferenceChanged(mPreferences, null);

            firstCurrent = new Point();
            firstOriginal = new Point();
            firstDes = new Point();
            secondCurrent = new Point();
            secondOriginal = new Point();
            secondDes = new Point();
            thirdCurrent = new Point();
            thirdOriginal = new Point();
            thirdDes = new Point();
            forthCurrent = new Point();
            forthOriginal = new Point();
            forthDes = new Point();

            firstLine = new Line();
            secondLine = new Line();
            thirdLine = new Line();

            rand = new Random();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
            setTouchEventsEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawPattern);
        }

        Boolean isVisible = true;

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            isVisible = visible;
            if (visible) {
                drawFrame();
            } else {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawPattern);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                     int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);

            initFrameParams();

            drawFrame();

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Surface Changed!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"surface created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            isVisible = false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawPattern);
            back = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,
                                     float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {

            //drawFrame();
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Offset Changed!!! xOffset : " + xOffset + "yOffset : " + yOffset + "xStep : " + xStep + "yStep : " + yStep + "xPixels : " + xPixels + "yPixels : " + yPixels ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            System.out.println("Offset Changed!!! xOffset : " + xOffset + "yOffset : " + yOffset + "xStep : " + xStep + "yStep : " + yStep + "xPixels : " + xPixels + "yPixels : " + yPixels );
        }

        /*
         * Store the position of the touch event so we can use it for drawing
         * later
         */

        float lastX = -1;
        float lastY = -1;

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                lastX = event.getX();
                lastY = event.getY();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Touched " + lastX + " " + lastY,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
//            else {
//                lastX = -1;
//                lastY = -1;
//            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            firstSentence = mPreferences.getString("text_one",getString(R.string.first_text_default));
            secondSentence = mPreferences.getString("text_two",getString(R.string.second_text_default));
            thirdSentence = mPreferences.getString("text_three",getString(R.string.third_text_default));
            forthSentence = mPreferences.getString("text_four",getString(R.string.forth_text_default));
            whichTheme = mPreferences.getString("theme_selector",getString(R.string.defTheme));
            coverEnabled = Boolean.valueOf( mPreferences.getBoolean("cover_enabled",true));
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),((Integer)mPreferences.getInt("text_one_size",50)).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            firstSize = Integer.valueOf(mPreferences.getString("text_one_size","50"));
            secondSize = Integer.valueOf(mPreferences.getString("text_two_size","50"));
            thirdSize = Integer.valueOf(mPreferences.getString("text_three_size","50"));
            forthSize = Integer.valueOf(mPreferences.getString("text_four_size","50"));
            firstColor = mPreferences.getString("text_one_color","#ffffff");
            secondColor = mPreferences.getString("text_two_color","#ffffff");
            thirdColor = mPreferences.getString("text_three_color","#ffffff");
            forthColor = mPreferences.getString("text_four_color","#ffffff");
            back = null;
        }

        /*
        Custom Codes
         */

        private final Runnable  mDrawPattern    = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                drawFrame();
            }
        };


        private final Handler mHandler      = new Handler();

        void drawFrame()
        {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;
            try
            {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null)
                {
                    // draw something
//                    c.drawColor(0xff000000);
                    drawBack(c);
                    drawTextOne(c);
                    drawTextTwo(c);
                    drawTextThree(c);
                    drawTextFour(c);
//                    drawLineOne(c);
//                    drawLineTwo(c);
//                    drawLineThree(c);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (c != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawPattern);
            if (isVisible)
            {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawPattern, 1000 / 25);
            }
        }

        class Line{
            public Point leftTop;
            public Point leftTopOrg;
            public Point leftTopDes;
            public Point rightButton;
            public Point rightButtonOrg;
            public Point rightButtonDes;

            public Boolean dir;

            public Line(){
                leftTop = new Point();
                leftTopOrg = new Point();
                leftTopDes = new Point();
                rightButton = new Point();
                rightButtonDes = new Point();
                rightButtonOrg = new Point();
            }
        }

        private void drawLineOne(Canvas c) {
            c.save();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            c.drawRect(firstLine.leftTop.x,firstLine.leftTop.y,firstLine.rightButton.x,firstLine.rightButton.y,paint);

            nextLocation(firstLine.leftTop, firstLine.leftTopOrg, firstLine.leftTopDes, firstLine.dir, 20);
            nextLocation(firstLine.rightButton, firstLine.rightButtonOrg, firstLine.rightButtonDes, firstLine.dir, 20);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firstSentence,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            c.restore();
        }

        private void drawLineTwo(Canvas c) {
            c.save();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            c.drawRect(secondLine.leftTop.x,secondLine.leftTop.y,secondLine.rightButton.x,secondLine.rightButton.y,paint);

            nextLocation(secondLine.leftTop, secondLine.leftTopOrg, secondLine.leftTopDes, secondLine.dir, 20);
            nextLocation(secondLine.rightButton, secondLine.rightButtonOrg, secondLine.rightButtonDes, secondLine.dir, 20);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firstSentence,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            c.restore();
        }

        private void drawLineThree(Canvas c) {
            c.save();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            c.drawRect(thirdLine.leftTop.x,thirdLine.leftTop.y,thirdLine.rightButton.x,thirdLine.rightButton.y,paint);

            nextLocation(thirdLine.leftTop, thirdLine.leftTopOrg, thirdLine.leftTopDes, thirdLine.dir, 20);
            nextLocation(thirdLine.rightButton, thirdLine.rightButtonOrg, thirdLine.rightButtonDes, thirdLine.dir, 20);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firstSentence,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            c.restore();
        }

        private void drawBack(Canvas c) {
            c.save();

            if (back == null){
                if (whichTheme.equals("t1")) {
                    back = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.p1), drawHere.width(), drawHere.height(), false);
                }
                else if(whichTheme.equals("t2")){
                    back = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.p2), drawHere.width(), drawHere.height(), false);
                }
                else{
                    back = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.p3), drawHere.width(), drawHere.height(), false);
                }
            }
            if (cover == null){
                cover = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cover1), drawHere.width(), drawHere.height(), false);
            }

            c.drawBitmap(back,0,0,null);
            if (coverEnabled) {
                c.drawBitmap(cover, 0, 0, null);
            }

            c.restore();
        }

        private void drawTextOne(Canvas c) {
            c.save();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(firstColor));
            paint.setTextSize(firstSize);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            c.drawText(firstSentence,firstCurrent.x,firstCurrent.y,paint);
            nextLocation(firstCurrent,firstOriginal,firstDes,firstDir, 100);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firstSentence,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            c.restore();
        }

        // from Org to Des
        Boolean firstDir = true;
        Boolean secondDir = true;
        Boolean thirdDir = true;
        Boolean forthDir = true;

        private void nextLocation(Point f1, Point f2, Point f3, Boolean dir,Integer limit) { // f1 : current , f2 : Org , f3 : Destination
            if (f1.x == f3.x && f1.y == f3.y && dir){
                f3.x = f2.x-(limit/2)+rand.nextInt(limit);
                f3.y = f2.y-(limit/2)+rand.nextInt(limit);
                dir = false;
            }
            if (f1.x == f2.x && f1.y == f2.y && !dir){
                dir = true;
            }
            else if (!dir){
                if (f1.x > f2 .x)
                    f1.x--;
                else if (f1.x < f2.x)
                    f1.x++;
                if (f1.y > f2 .y)
                    f1.y--;
                else if (f1.y < f2.y)
                    f1.y++;
            }
            else{
                if (f1.x > f3 .x)
                    f1.x--;
                else if (f1.x < f3.x)
                    f1.x++;
                if (f1.y > f3 .y)
                    f1.y--;
                else if (f1.y < f3.y)
                    f1.y++;
            }
        }

        private void drawTextTwo(Canvas c) {
            c.save();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(secondColor));
            paint.setTextSize(secondSize);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            c.drawText(secondSentence,secondCurrent.x,secondCurrent.y,paint);
            nextLocation(secondCurrent,secondOriginal,secondDes,secondDir, 100);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firstSentence,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            c.restore();
        }

        private void drawTextThree(Canvas c) {
            c.save();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(thirdColor));
            paint.setTextSize(thirdSize);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            c.drawText(thirdSentence,thirdCurrent.x,thirdCurrent.y,paint);
            nextLocation(thirdCurrent,thirdOriginal,thirdDes,thirdDir, 100);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firstSentence,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            c.restore();
        }

        private void drawTextFour(Canvas c) {
            c.save();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(forthColor));
            paint.setTextSize(forthSize);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            c.drawText(forthSentence,forthCurrent.x,forthCurrent.y,paint);
            nextLocation(forthCurrent,forthOriginal,forthDes,forthDir, 100);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firstSentence,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            c.restore();
        }

        float nextRight = 200 , nextButton = 200;

        private void drawBlue(Canvas c) {

            c.save();
            c.drawColor(0xff000000);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            c.drawRect(100, 100, nextRight, nextButton, paint);

            if (nextRight > 200){
                nextButton --;
            }
            if (nextButton > 200){
                nextRight --;
            }

            if (lastX > 200 && lastY > 200){
                nextRight = lastX;
                lastX = -1;
                nextButton = lastY;
                lastY = -1;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Refreshed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Rect drawHere;

        Boolean isHorizontal;

        void initFrameParams(){
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            display.getMetrics(metrics);

            drawHere = new Rect(0, 0, metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);

            int rotation = display.getOrientation();
            if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180)
                isHorizontal = false;
            else
                isHorizontal = true;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"isHorizontal : " + isHorizontal.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //System.out.println("mHorizontal "+isHorizontal);
            //System.out.println("mShape "+mShape);

            Integer heightPart = drawHere.height()/8;

            firstOriginal.set(drawHere.width()/2,drawHere.height()/5);
            firstCurrent.set(firstOriginal.x,firstOriginal.y);
            firstDes.set(firstOriginal.x,firstOriginal.y);

            firstLine.leftTop.set(drawHere.width()/10,firstOriginal.y+heightPart-10);
            firstLine.leftTopOrg.set(firstLine.leftTop.x,firstLine.leftTop.y);
            firstLine.leftTopDes.set(firstLine.leftTop.x,firstLine.leftTop.y);
            firstLine.rightButton.set(9*drawHere.width()/10,firstOriginal.y+heightPart+10);
            firstLine.rightButtonOrg.set(firstLine.rightButton.x,firstLine.rightButton.y);
            firstLine.rightButtonDes.set(firstLine.rightButton.x,firstLine.rightButton.y);
            firstLine.dir = true;

            secondOriginal.set(drawHere.width()/2,2*drawHere.height()/5);
            secondCurrent.set(secondOriginal.x,secondOriginal.y);
            secondDes.set(secondOriginal.x,secondOriginal.y);

            secondLine.leftTop.set(drawHere.width()/10,secondOriginal.y+heightPart-10);
            secondLine.leftTopOrg.set(secondLine.leftTop.x,secondLine.leftTop.y);
            secondLine.leftTopDes.set(secondLine.leftTop.x,secondLine.leftTop.y);
            secondLine.rightButton.set(9*drawHere.width()/10,secondOriginal.y+heightPart+10);
            secondLine.rightButtonOrg.set(secondLine.rightButton.x,secondLine.rightButton.y);
            secondLine.rightButtonDes.set(secondLine.rightButton.x,secondLine.rightButton.y);
            secondLine.dir = true;

            thirdOriginal.set(drawHere.width()/2,3*drawHere.height()/5);
            thirdCurrent.set(thirdOriginal.x,thirdOriginal.y);
            thirdDes.set(thirdOriginal.x,thirdOriginal.y);

            thirdLine.leftTop.set(drawHere.width()/10,thirdOriginal.y+heightPart-10);
            thirdLine.leftTopOrg.set(thirdLine.leftTop.x,thirdLine.leftTop.y);
            thirdLine.leftTopDes.set(thirdLine.leftTop.x,thirdLine.leftTop.y);
            thirdLine.rightButton.set(9*drawHere.width()/10,thirdOriginal.y+heightPart+10);
            thirdLine.rightButtonOrg.set(thirdLine.rightButton.x,thirdLine.rightButton.y);
            thirdLine.rightButtonDes.set(thirdLine.rightButton.x,thirdLine.rightButton.y);
            thirdLine.dir = true;

            forthOriginal.set(drawHere.width()/2,4*drawHere.height()/5);
            forthCurrent.set(forthOriginal.x,forthOriginal.y);
            forthDes.set(forthOriginal.x,forthOriginal.y);
        }
    }
}
```

LiveWallpaperSettings.java

```
package ir.cclever.fourmyword;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class LiveWallpaperSettings extends PreferenceActivity
    implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(LiveWallpaper.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.livewallpaper_settings);
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key)
    {
    }
}
```

The story is as below:

I was working on an example of live wallpaper and everything was good. When I decided to publish my program, I changed the package name by refactoring in Android Studio and then renaming the folders in directory and then edit the files where needed! I mean the packages definition in the top of each file.

Now the wallpaper preview is ok but when I want to go to the settings page or set the wallpaper, I see an error.